# Oracle substr(), implicit conversion?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I am facing an issue with Oracle SQLs `substr()` function.

It looks as though `substr()` acts beyond its stated purpose so that,

`substr(some.field, 0, 7) <> '1598200'`

where

`some.field = '1598200, 123456'`

Coming into play here,

```
select sum(t.amount)
from ivtransaction t
inner join ivpaymentreminders p on p.transactionid = t.transactionid
left join ivinvoice i on i.invoiceid = t.invoiceid
where substr(p.collectiveinvoiceno, 0, 7) = '1598200'
```

In `p.collectiveinvoiceno`, 4 records are expected to turn up:

```
rownum | p.collectiveinvoiceno
---------------------------------
1      | 1598200
2      | 1598200
3      | 1598200, 123456
4      | 1598200, 456789
```

But only rows 1 and 2 turn up and add into `sum(t.amount)`.

- When tested on its own, `substr(p.collectiveinvoiceno, 0, 7)` extracts the correct values
- Converting left and right sides of the argument using `to_char` makes no difference

Is this an implicit conversion of some sort? If so, how to fix it?

Thankful for any ideas,

Ingrid

EDIT: As it turns out, the substr(field, 1, 7) comparison didn't catch 4/4 rows because the target string is at the back in rows 3 and 4, NOT leading. I was fooled because in the application, the target string is displayed as leading!! I'm a beginner so this was very helpful anyway, thanks for all your input. Ingrid

Comment: Maybe problem is in another place. (inner join to ivpaymentreminders). Also you can replace substr with (`where instr(some_value,'1598200') >0;`)

Comment: strings in Oracle are numerated from 1. So it should be `substr(p.collectiveinvoiceno, 1, 7)`. But not sure if it helps in your situation, because problem as well could be in joins. Remove your `WHERE` and check if you get all necessary rows.

Comment: From the Oracle documentation: When position is 0 (zero), then it is treated as 1

Comment: Going from inner to left join doesn't make a difference, the inner is just to exclude records from table a that don't have an entry in table b. But instr() did the trick, thanks Arkadiusz. Thanks Tatiana for your tip on correct *substr() index use.

Comment: Try, `dump(p.collectiveinvoiceno)` to see if there are non-printing control codes. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm

Comment: Thanks Shannon. Input `dump(p.collectiveinvoiceno, 1017)` gets `Typ=1 Len=16 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: 1,5,7,0,1,4,2,,, ,1,5,9,8,2,0,0` of the content which is `1570142, 1598200`. So it is clear why substr() caught only 2/4 rows: It checks the leading 7 digits while the target string is at the back! I was fooled because in the application, the target string is displayed as leading. Ahh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> substr(p.collectiveinvoiceno, 0, 7)

It is a bad practice to use `0` as **start position** in **SUBSTR**, you should use `1`. Although, documentation states:

> If position is 0, then it is treated as 1.

There is no problem with the `SUBSTR` in the filter predicate, it will fetch all the 4 rows.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '1598200' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '1598200' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '1598200, 123456' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '1598200, 456789' FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT str, substr(str, 1, 7) FROM DATA
  8  WHERE substr(str, 1, 7) = '1598200';

STR             SUBSTR(
--------------- -------
1598200         1598200
1598200         1598200
1598200, 123456 1598200
1598200, 456789 1598200
```

There is no need to use **TO_CHAR** as you already have string data type on both sides. So, there is no question about **implicit data type conversion**. Look at the **explain plan**:

```
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 560839587

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     4 |    36 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW            |      |     4 |    36 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL      |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL     |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    FAST DUAL     |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    FAST DUAL     |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   6 |    FAST DUAL     |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

13 rows selected.
```

> But only rows 1 and 2 turn up and add into sum(t.amount)

It depends on the **JOIN** condition. The filer predicate is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Lalit, my expectation exactly but I still can't fetch all 4 rows using substr(), returning 2/4 rows, while using instr() 4/4 rows are returned, both versions run with the inner join in place.